# what will be the best approach to accept Bitcoin payment instantly?

Tags: payment, zero-confirmation

How could I receive Bitcoin instant payment?

Comment: are you planning to run your own server or using some third party?

Comment: Re "instantly" - see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/48548/13866

Comment: I'm planning for my own node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin takes 10 minutes for a transaction. It is advised to wait for a 6-block confirmation for a safety. This takes a maximum time of 1 hour. So, instant payment is really difficult.

If for your business, you could try services like [coinpayments](https://www.coinpayments.net).  They have different strategies which reduces users risk.

Comment: They provide plug-ins which can included in your website